# Qt is not able to load some images

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to load two png images via QPixmap, one loads effortlessly, while the second one doesn't load at all, no matter what method of file loading I'm using. It also worked with some jpg and bmp files without any problems. What could potentially cause such issues?

I'm including both images below and in a release build. I'm using Qt 5.9.2.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent )
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPixmap pm("f4f2dda9605b54f8ff706d5a25d36a45f8f4dc50b025e2c91a375541719b3d5c.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(pm);
    ui->label->setScaledContents(true); // Works

    QPixmap pm2("background.png");
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(pm2);
    ui->label_2->setScaledContents(true); // Doesn't work
}
```

Images:
https://ibb.co/HP1skr3
https://ibb.co/Swpmdny

Project:
https://easyupload.io/rspu0k
Release:
https://easyupload.io/vos6xs

Comment: Are any errors printed to the console?

Comment: No, no errors in console. File is detected properly, f.e. when using `qDebug() << QFile::exists("background.png")`

Comment: You might want to try https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimagereader.html which gives a bit more feedback

Comment: @AlanBirtles unluckily the same behaviour, reader doesn't return any error. It seems like there's something unhandleable with the second png, but I have no idea what.

Comment: I'm pretty sure QFile::exists("background.png") returns false.

Comment: @chehrlic I've checked again and it return true for both files. If you're checking attached zips, please remember, that I've included images only in release folder, maybe you're missing them. You can also try to simply rename background into f4f2, the result will be that left image will be missing, instead of right. It really seems like there's something wrong with this png file, but I cannot investigate what could possibly cause this.

https://i.ibb.co/LQbgG0x/obraz.png

Comment: Load it as QImage. Does it produce a null image, or does the image have some size and/or colour depth? Does it help if you re-save the image with a paint application? How about shorter name, does that affect what happens?

Comment: @hyde Loading with QImage returns invalid state: https://i.ibb.co/w7Fftf8/obraz.png Changing file name doesn't help. However resaving with Paint actually helped - but only if I choose the option "Save as". If I simply make some changes and use "Save" it won't work. Would it seem like some png metadata is corrupted?  
Working - https://i.ibb.co/4TgtSGK/DDbackground.png
Not working - https://i.ibb.co/WvxvwkN/1background.png

Comment: Opening in TweakPNG returns "unrecognised file format" error. `file` command returns `PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 535 x 38 x 24`. I've changed extension to bmp, but still it's not loading. However, clearly something is messed up, since it's not a png file. It's being opened by image viewers, but Qt can't handle with it.

Comment: Well, if you can be bothered, filing a Qt bug report might be a thing to do. Most likely the image file is somehow against the png spec, and other programs just don't care. But it could also be a bug in Qt image loading, and the image is completely valid. As a solution to you concrete problem: if you _must_ use that actual image file, you may have to add an extra library to load the file, one which can read it, otherwise just re-save the file so it works.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing relative filepath by only giving the filename.

Qt doc states:

```
If fileName contains a relative path (e.g. the filename only) the relevant file must be found relative to the runtime working directory.
```

Is your file available from the working directory? Working directory can be IDE dependent.

Options are:

1. Give full path to the file
2. Keep the file in working directory
3. Add the file to resource file and access it via its resource name https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html

Comment: Yes, it is available, those two images are included in exactly the same manner. Using absolute path works exactly the same, somehow file `background.png` is still not loaded. In my case I want user to be able to use his/her own images, so I don't want to encapsulate them into resources.